# Can someone explain to me the relationships and constrains of this database as well as which normal form is this?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

A relational database that stores and organizes data points that are related to one another:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is Second Normal Form (2NF)

The entity should be considered already in 1NF, and all attributes within the entity should depend solely on the unique identifier of the entity.